# How to add the Python Help and Syntax Box to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-window

ArcGIS Desktop features a "Help and Syntax Window" in the Python prompt:

[image]

ArcGIS Pro has removed this feature, which was useful as it both listed and *explained* parameters:

[image]

Is there any way to add a similar window to ArcGIS Pro? At the moment the help() function is the only option I am aware of, which requires more typing and clutters the transcript.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, there is no "help" specific box attached to the Python window in ArcGIS Pro. It's just the in-line intellisense showing parameter name/order.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll mark this as the answer after leaving some time for other answers first. Have you any suggestions for the best way to get details on parameters beyond their order without just using help()/Google? (If alternatives even exist...)